# Delete text before spaces(tab) using regex

Tags: notepad++, regex, text-editing

I have a small problem.Tried looking for some solutions but couldn't find any.
I have a big document that has data like this:

```
0002ssap    10763
0003    0003
0003    33699425
0003    3557471
00031   00000
```

I want to delete everything before the 2nd text part so it looks like this:

```
10763
0003
33699425
3557471
00000
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use Replace, select the Regular Expression option, enter

`^.*  +  (if you only need to remove spaces)`

or

`^.*[ ,\t]+ (if you need to remove tabs also)`

in the "Find what" field and nothing in the "Replace with" field

Caveat: If you have a line like

1234  afe ngh

only ngh would remain

Comment: I tried your solution but I end up with something like this
http://prntscr.com/f8te9e
It says 87 occurrences but the document has few million lines and every line is similar (data1    data2)

Comment: mhh, could it be many of these are actually tabs and not whitespaces? In that case try `^.*[ ,\t]+`. You can check whether they are tabs or whitespaces by selecting "Show All characters" from the View-> Show Symbol menu

Comment: The second solution worked like a charm. Thanks for the help, You saved me few years of work :D

Comment: You're welcome. :) Will edit the answer